# How to add users to the aspnet_Users table using membership provider or role provider?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, configuration

I want to add users to the aspnet_Users table using my own form and provide roles to them. How can I do this? Please explain me. If you can provide example code, that will be great. Please help me someone. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Great question! The most simple answer is to use the Web Site Administration Tool ASP.Net provides: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

After getting intitial testing out of the way, you undoubtedly will want to do this programmically. You can do this by calling `Membership.CreateUser()` as follows:

```
   Membership.CreateUser( 
       model.UserName,  
       model.Password,  
       model.Email,  
       null,  
       null,  
       model.IsApproved, 
       out createStatus);
```

Also, the application code provided when building the sample MVCx application provides some great snippets.